# Updating specific area of table in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Ok I am trying to update a specific area of a table in postgresql

I want it to find the user that goes along with the table

and then update the information I have

like in this case the email is the user name that it needs to look for.

it needs to add in areas like $aboutSelf, $hobbies, $music, $tv, $sports

so ya I have no idea how to do this lol ^.^ I only know how to add stuff from scratch. like create a non existing user

```
CREATE TABLE chatterprofileinfo(
    Id SERIAL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    aboutSelf VARCHAR(255),
    hobbies VARCHAR(255),
    music VARCHAR(255),
    tv VARCHAR(255),
    sports VARCHAR(255),
    lastLogin DATE
);
```

The PHP im currently using

```
<?php

$error=false;

$aboutSelfError="";
$hobbiesError="";
$musicError="";
$tvError="";
$sportsError="";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

    $aboutSelf="";
    $hobbies="";
    $music="";
    $tv="";
    $sports="";
    $error=false;

}
else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $error=false;

    $aboutSelf=trim($_POST["aboutSelfTA"]);
    $hobbies=trim($_POST["hobbiesTA"]);
    $music=trim($_POST["musicTA"]);
    $tv=trim($_POST["tvTA"]);
    $sports=trim($_POST["sportsTA"]);

    if(strlen($aboutSelf)>255) {

        $aboutSelfError="Maximum of 255 characters please shorten";

        $error=true;

    }

    if(strlen($hobbies)>255) {

        $hobbiesError="Maximum of 255 characters please shorten";

        $error=true;

    }

    if(strlen($music)>255) {

        $musicError="Maximum of 255 characters please shorten";

        $error=true;

    }

    if(strlen($tv)>255) {

        $tvError="Maximum of 255 characters please shorten";

        $error=true;

    }

    if(strlen($sports)>255) {

        $sportsError="Maximum of 255 characters please shorten";

        $error=true;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: hmm, you are going to have to give more info and possible show the table schema or what you are trying to do.  There really isn't much to go off here.  If you just want to learn how to do an UPDATE you can look at the postgres docs.

Comment: ok sorry I will try and add more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-update.html

```
UPDATE
  users
SET
  aboutSelf='...',
  hobbies='...',
  music='...',
  tv='...',
  sports='...'
WHERE
  email='something'
```

edit: a self-contained example using [pg_prepare()](http://docs.php.net/pg_prepare):

```
$pg = pg_connect("dbname=test user=localonly password=localonly");
if ( !$pg ) {
  die('connect failed ');
}

// create a temporary/test table
pg_query($pg, '
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpchatter (
    id SERIAL, 
    email varchar,
    aboutSelf varchar,
    hobbies varchar,
    UNIQUE (email)
  )
');

// fill in some test data
pg_query("INSERT INTO tmpchatter(email, aboutSelf, hobbies) VALUES ('emailA','aboutA','hobbiesA')") or die(pq_last_error($pg));
pg_query("INSERT INTO tmpchatter(email, aboutSelf, hobbies) VALUES ('emailB','aboutB','hobbiesB')") or die(pq_last_error($pg));
pg_query("INSERT INTO tmpchatter(email, aboutSelf, hobbies) VALUES ('emailC','aboutC','hobbiesC')") or die(pq_last_error($pg));

// let's see what we've got so far
$result = pg_query('SELECT email,aboutSelf,hobbies FROM tmpchatter') or die(pq_last_error($pg));
echo "query result #1:\n";
while ( false!==($row=pg_fetch_row($result)) ) {
  echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}

// now let's update a specific record
// the "interesting" part

// first the parameters we want to use
$email = 'emailB';
$about = 'about me....';
$hobbies = 'breathing, eating';

// prepare the statement. Put placeholders where you want to "insert" parameters
pg_prepare($pg, '', '
  UPDATE
    tmpchatter
  SET
    aboutSelf = $1,
    hobbies = $2
  WHERE
    email = $3
') or die(pg_last_error());

// execute the statement + provide the parameters
// With prepared statements you don't have to worry about escaping the values to avoid sql injections
pg_execute($pg, '', array($about, $hobbies, $email)) or die(pg_last_error());

// let's check the result
$result = pg_query('SELECT email,aboutSelf,hobbies FROM tmpchatter') or die(pq_last_error($pg));
echo "query result #2:\n";
while ( false!==($row=pg_fetch_row($result)) ) {
  echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
query result #1:
emailA, selfA, hobbiesA
emailB, selfB, hobbiesB
emailC, selfC, hobbiesC

query result #2:
emailA, selfA, hobbiesA
emailC, selfC, hobbiesC
emailB, about me...., breathing, eating
```

Comment: would $query = pg_query("UPDATE chatterprofileinfo SET aboutSelf='$aboutSelf', hobbies='$hobbies', music='$music', tv='$tv', sports='$sports' WHERE email='something'"); work then?

Comment: Probably yes. (see http://docs.php.net/pg_escape_string) Does it have to be pg\_query or could it also be pg\_prepare or maybe PDO ( http://docs.php.net/pdo )

Answer (score 2):

Use the [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) query?

I use W3schools.com for most of my SQL references. Very handy site!

Might be too generalized an answer but can't go off much more without a schema.